# Convert Single Array to multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I new to PHP, I need to convert single dimension array into multi dimension array in php

I have data like this, need to minimize as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => David
            [1] => School
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => Home
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => Cinema
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Paul
            [1] => Park
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rossie
            [1] => Playground
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rossie
            [1] => Hotel
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rossie
            [1] => Hospital
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 29
        )
)
```

And I want convert it to multidimensional

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => David 
                            (
                                [0] => School 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                            )
            )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Paul 
                            (
                                [0] => Home 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                                [1] => Cinema 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                                [1] => Park 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                            )
            )
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Rossie 
                            (
                                [0] => Playground 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                                [1] => Hotel 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                                [1] => Hospital 
                                (
                                    [0] => 19
                                    [1] => 29
                                    [2] => 39
                                    [3] => 49
                                )

                            )
            )
        )


)
```

I hope you get an idea. But my function doesn't do this correctly or maybe there are other ways to do this easier ?

I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks

Comment: Your function? Show it to us.

Comment: And what if there's multiple people with the same first name? The keys will be overwritten. At least if you use the first name as the key. If you're using indexes you're still fine.

Comment: @Torxed The first name is fixed.

Comment: @ThiruvarasuKTangarasi Yes, but a assoiative array *(dictionary/hashmap)* won't take two keys with the same name. And I'm guessing the name list won't be actually fixed in any real work scenario. Have a look at this for instance: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d07178e9908bdc09df330935563aee193dba9aa3 (You're only getting one "David" out of it)

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to do it:

```
<?php
$arr = [array('David','School',19,29),
        array('Paul','Home',19,29),
        array('Paul','Cinema',19,29),
        array('Paul','Park',19,29),
        array('Rossie','Playground',19,29),
        array('Rossie','Hotel',19,29),
        array('Rossie','Hospital',19,29)];

// Get all names.
$names = array_unique(array_map(function($value){return $value[0];}, $arr));
$places = [];
// Create the multidimensional array, grouping by name.
foreach($names as $key => $name){
    $tempArr = [];
    foreach($arr as $record){
        if($record[0] === $name){
            $tempArr[][$record[1]] = array_slice($record,2);
        }
    }
    $places[][][$name] = $tempArr;
}
print("<pre>".print_r($places,true)."</pre>");
```

This will return the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [David] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [School] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Paul] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Home] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Cinema] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Park] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Rossie] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [Playground] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [Hotel] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [Hospital] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 19
                                            [1] => 29
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```